# Calculate each table row values using jquery automatically

Tags: jquery

I have this data in my table

cost     postage    profit     paypal     selling price
 2.75            3           6            5            **16.75** 
 5.75            3           6            5            **19.75** 
 3.99            3           6            5            **17.99**

The value in the **cost** table is being fetch from the **database** and the values in the **postage**, **profit**, and **paypal** are both constant. When i update the **cost** value in the database it will now display in the table and do automatic calculation based on what value i updated and display the answer in the **selling_price** column. I am a bit confused on how to implement client-side calculation in jQuery. Could anyone help me solve this one. Any help will be much more appreciated.

Here is the code that i created

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 

    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup handler to trigger sum event
            $(".txt").each(function() 
            {
                $(this).keyup(function() {
                    calculateSellingPrice();
                });
            });
        });

        function calculateSellingPrice() {
            var sellingprice = 0;
            //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
            $(".txt").each(function() {
                //add only if the value is number
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    sellingprice += parseFloat(this.value);
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
                }
                else if (this.value.length != 0){
                $(this).css("background-color", "red");
               }
            });
            $("#sellingprice").html(sellingprice.toFixed(2));
        }
    </script>   
</head>
<body>  

        <table border = "0">    
            <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
                <td><center>Selling Price</center></td>
                <td><center>Cost</center></td>
                <td><center>Postage</center></td>
                <td><center>Profit</center></td>
                <td><center>Paypal</center></td>
            </tr> 

            <?php

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT cost FROM table");
            while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "<input type='text' id='sellingprice' name='sellingprice' size='10' />"; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "<input class='txt' type='text' id='cost' name='cost' size='10' value='$myrow[1]' />"; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "<input class='txt' type='text' id='postage' name='postage' size='10' value='3' />"; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "<input class='txt' type='text' id='profit' name='profit' size='10' value='6' />"; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo "<input class='txt' type='text' id='paypal' name='paypal' size='10' value='5' />"; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
                <?php
            }
                ?>
        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

i just found the jquery code in the internet although i understand a bit about the jquery code but i'm stock and can't continue.

Comment: Take note of the `{}` button in the editor when formatting your code and space-delimited content. You don't need `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` to accomplish this. Also, where is the markup?

Comment: how long did it take you to make that with all those `&nbsp;`s?

Comment: Is this like what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/jxuvT/

Comment: We would need to see your actual HTML to know how to advise.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: This is what i'm looking for but the code is not functioning.

Comment: I would put the code in a standalone function.  Then you can attach it to more than one event and the code is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through and calculate each row independently.
In your example the jQuery selects every cell input at once, does the calculations then updates the display of all "#sellingprice" inputs. There wont be any display changes though because "#sellingprice" requires updateing via .val() rather than .html()

This is closer to what you would need.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').each(function(){
        var total = 0;
        $(this).find('.txt:not(:first)').each(function(){
            total += (+$(this).val());
        });
        $(this).find('.txt:first').val(total).css("background-color", "#FEFFB0");
    });
});
```

- loop through each tr: $('tr').each(functi...
- set or, reset the counter: var total = 0;
- loop through all inputs (excluding the first total one): $(this).find('.txt:not(:first)')...
- set new total: $(this).find('.txt:first').val(total)...

Comment: yeah based on my codes it just only calculate all the cell values. i'll try to update my codes using this.

Comment: Great. you may need minor tweaking to get it to work - just updates to show what each line does

Comment: Can you guide me some of my questions regarding this project? What if i'm going to select some fields in my table for the calculation.Let's say i want only the cost and postage to calculate and not to include the profit and paypal. how to implement this in jQuery?

Comment: Replace the jQuery selector: ".txt:not(:first)" with one that identifies such fields: "input[name=cost],input[name=postage]" :)

Comment: I've followed your idea but then i'm stock and can't continue. i replaced the ".txt:not(:first) with input[name=cost],input[name=postage]. may you guide me the calculation process?

Comment: For each row the variable "total" starts at 0. As it loops through each input it adds its value to the sum of "total". "total" is then added to the first input. - is this what you need?

Comment: I've tried working with your code and it works fine to me. Thanks for this. I'll just post if i have some trouble working on some areas :)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this article u can see how to get each value from table row or column
http://www.amitpatil.me/table-manipulation-with-jquery/

Comment: can i do calculation based on your example table sir?

Comment: Yes u can...just use parseInt() function to convert string value to integer value